# How to Bind a click event to a Div inside Table Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<table class="table lsttabl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div id="NameLabel">Customer Name</div></th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Registered</th>
        <th id="Date1Label">Created Date</th>
        <th id="Date2Label">Last Updated Date</th>
        <th id="Date3Label">Expiry Date</th>
        <th id="UserCountLabel">User Count</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>Configure</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I am trying to Bind Event using the code below

```
$("#NameLabel").click(function () { alert("hello"); });
```

I tried many variations but it is not working.. 
Please Share your knowledge.

Comment: The problem is outside the code we see. There could be many reasons, from a generated html, a css preventing the click, your code not inside document ready, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF this code is dynamically added after the page loads, you might need to use the delegate function.

```
$('body').delegate('click','#NameLabel',function(){
  alert("hello");
});
```

Here I am using the `body` selector as I can be sure that the body element was there when the page was loaded. If there is another parent element that you are loading the dynamic content into, you can use it instead of attaching the event to the body.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind it in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to make sure that element is available before access by the script.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/sBsMd/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#NameLabel").click(function () {
          alert("hello");
   });

});
```

Comment: Don't you think a comment would have been more appropriate for what is just one wild guess about one of the many possible causes of the problem ?

Comment: @dystroy the code is working and its more likely from the posted code in the question that the element would have been accessed before it is ready as OP did not have document.ready in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table.lsttabl thead th div[id$=NameLabel]').click(function(){
    alert("hii");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very wrong. When you have an id, **do** use `#theId`. It's faster and it's enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'th', function(){
        console.log(event.target);
    });
});
```

if you want it specifically for #NameLabel,
Then change the on selector to '#NameLabel'

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#NameLabel').click(function () {
            alert("Customer Name Clicked");
        });
    });
</script>
<table class="table lsttabl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><div id="NameLabel">Customer Name</div></th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Registered</th>
        <th id="Date1Label">Created Date</th>
        <th id="Date2Label">Last Updated Date</th>
        <th id="Date3Label">Expiry Date</th>
        <th id="UserCountLabel">User Count</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>Configure</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't forget to import JQuery Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

here's a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9PNk6/

```
$("#NameLabel").on('click',function () {
   alert("hello");
});
```